# Calculating the number of black nodes in each path in Red Black Tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, red-black-tree

What recursion algorithm should I use to calculate the number of black nodes in each path?

Comment: What problem do you face when doing this with recursion? BTW: if this really is a red-back tree, you only have to do this for *one* path, as it is guaranteed that this number is the same for all paths.

Comment: I would say the canonical approach would be to recursively traverse the tree and increment your black-nodes-counter, whenever you find a black node.

Answer (score 0):

In a red-black tree, the number of black nodes on any path is constant. The process can be broken into two parts.

Part 1: get a path. Here, a path is defined as a sequence of nodes.

To get a path from the empty tree, return the path containing only the empty tree.

To get a path from a non-empty tree, get the path of its left child and append the non-empty tree to this path.

Part 2: count the number of black nodes in the path.

Hopefully, this one is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

*What recursion algorithm should I use to calculate the number of black nodes in each path?*

None. Use an iterative approach. So if you start from the root, increment a counter initialised to 0 every time you see a black node including the root and keep going leftwards until the left node pointer is null. Whatever the count is, that is the black depth down any given path. In pseudo code:

```
int bcount = 0;
Node *currnode = GetRoot();

while (currnode != NULL)
{
  if (currnode->GetColour() == BLACK)
     ++bcount:
  currnode = currnode->Left();
}
```